# Installing specific tensorflow branch with pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am working on this [project](https://github.com/Conchylicultor/MusicGenerator) which was tested with `tensorflow v0.10.0rc0`.

I don't want to take any dependency risks, and I'm a bit confused about this syntax version (instead of less cryptic `1.0`, `1.1`, `1.2`, `1.3`and `1.4` versions)

so how do I safely install this `v0.10.0rc0` version using a `pip` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the history of official pip dependencies by doing the following:

`pypi.python.org/simple/<nameofpackage>/`

The one you're interested in is linked [here](https://pypi.python.org/simple/tensorflow/). These are all the available packages and there are some *v0.12* versions and alike there you can try.

To install a specific version of the package, do the following:

`pip install -I tensorflow==<version>`

**NOTE**: You can also install packages which are hosted externally by replacing `tensorflow==` with the HTTP link.

Answer (score 2):

To install a specific version with pip:

```
pip install tensorflow==<VERSION>
```

However, the specific version you want is not available via pip and I'm afraid **you're going to have to compile from source if you want to use it**.

Available pip3 versions (nov 18, 2017):

> 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0

Available pip2 versions (nov 18, 2017):

> 0.12.0rc0, 0.12.0rc1, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0